# How to define dependencies for lib-files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dependencies, manifest

How to determine dependencies for lib-file in C++ programmatically or with a tool (like depends.exe aka Dependency Walrer for DLL)? In particular I am interested in the defining of C-runtime version. My problem is that my DLL, compiled in MSVC2010 depends on CRT 8.0. I assume that this dependency inherited from some include lib-file. I want to verify this hypothesis and find the lib-file.

This code included in auto-generated manifest:

```
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT"
    version="8.0.50727.762" processorArchitecture="x86"
    publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dumpbin.exe which is installed with Visual Studio inside its /vc/bin/ directory.
You can have a look at :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c(v=VS.100).aspx